# opera browser not opening with the webbrowser module in python

Tags: python, opera, python-webbrowser

I am trying to open a URL in my default web browser which is opera. I provide the URL to the webbrowser.open() function but when executing, the program runs and terminates with no response whatsoever. What might be the problem?

I tried using the get() method to tell python explicitly to use opera but it is not working.

Comment: I have found a solution for this issue:

- **Description of the problem:**
  It turns out that the process of opening the Opera browser takes some time, and the program runs and terminates while the browser is trying to run.

- **Solution:**
  What worked for me is delaying the termination for 2 seconds using the `time` module as follows:

  ```python
  import webbrowser then 
  import time then 

  webbrowser.open('http://www.google.com') then 
  time.sleep(2)